# How can we pass a structure object if it is statically allocated in this case?

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct arrWrap {
    int arr[100];
};

struct arrWrap fun()
{
    struct arrWrap x;

    x.arr[0] = 10;
    x.arr[1] = 20;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    struct arrWrap x = fun();
    printf("%d %d", x.arr[0], x.arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is not this variable x in arrWrap a static variable and its lifetime is till the end of block
Or I am wrong ,I am trying to understand memory allocation i found using this way we can return array in c++ I know we can return vector rather then it.

Comment: Your question is tagged with c++, but you are using old C-style struct syntax. Are you sure you are using C++, not C?

Comment: Lifetime of local variables is till the end of the block, lifetime of local `static` variables is from the first time their definition is executed until end of the program. Since you return by copy, it's moo point.

Comment: `x` in `fun()` is not static. Its lifetime is from the point where it's created until the end of the block that it's created in, that is, until after the return from `fun()`.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a non-static local variable which is destroyed when the function `fun` returns. Which is perfectly fine.

You're probably worried because someone told you not to return pointers to local variables. You're not returning a pointer to `x`, so there is no problem here. The compiler will make sure to know where to put the return value, and it will copy the data from `x` into that space, when `return x;` runs, before `x` is destroyed. No problems.

Comment: Thanks i got it also you are correct about this point "You're probably worried because someone told you not to return pointers to local variables"